# How do I select data from SQL as an INT not a String?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code:

```
$TargetPlayerPosition = $GLOBALS['DATABASE']->uniquequery("SELECT total_rank FROM ".STATPOINTS." WHERE `id_owner` = '". $this->_fleet['fleet_target_owner'] ."';");
```

The problem is that I can't add +10 to `$TargetPlayerPosition`, because it's string. But in the DB, `total_rank` is an INT.

Comment: Why can't you add to a string? PHP will do the conversion for you, https://3v4l.org/eS014.

Comment: Are you sure `$TargetPlayerPosition` is a string and not a result object?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm just learning by trying to edit game from github.

Comment: what does print_r($TargetPlayerPosition) return? or var_dump($TargetPlayerPosition)

Comment: What does `var_dump($TargetPlayerPosition)` return?

Comment: The error.log just says: PHP Fatal error:  Unsupported operand types in ...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$TargetPlayerPosition = $GLOBALS['DATABASE']->uniquequery("SELECT total_rank FROM ".STATPOINTS." WHERE `id_owner` = '". $this->_fleet['fleet_target_owner'] ."';");
/* conversion to int */
$rank = (int) $TargetPlayerPosition;
/* do the required arithmetic */
/* $rank + 10 will work now */
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how are you retrieving the value from resultset after the query.
Generally You should get integer type value from a field which is integer in the DB.
If not then you can convert the value in php.

```
 $v = (int)$v;
 // Or.
 $v = intval($v);
```

You can use query like the following to add number dynamically while querying:

```
"SELECT (total_rank+10) AS total_rank FROM ".STATPOINTS." WHERE ..."
```

Even if the field is of string type can do the following:

```
"SELECT (CONVERT(total_rank, SIGNED INTEGER)+10) AS total_rank FROM ".STATPOINTS." WHERE ..."
```